# How to change DateTime picker time format in Blazor UI

Tags: abp, blazorise

I am having issues with Blazorise.DateEdit component.

`datetime` values are showing right in table columns as u can see in the image bellow.

[image]

Now, on editing is different story. first off, this is the code for rendering DateEdit component

[image]

and this is the result of it

[image]

how can i set DateEdit component to show date and time set in model property and also make it 24h format

Comment: https://blazorise.com/docs/components/date-picker/

Comment: ive already went through documentation with no luck. I need to use DateEdit component not DatePicker. There was mistake in code, instead of `@bind-Text` it should be `@bind-Date`. Date component is now showing date and time but still cant change time to 24h format

Answer (score 1):

solution was to change browser language from english us (am/pm format) to english british (24h time fomat)